# Server side angular way, dataTable properties are not applied with Get request

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

Trying to load sever-side dataTable with Get request,data loaded and table properties are not applied like pagination filters and search. Please provide if any solutions. I tried  with below code. Could you please help the issue,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 2,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
        this.http
          .get<DataTablesResponse>(
            'https://angular-datatables-demo-server.herokuapp.com/',
            dataTablesParameters
          )
          .subscribe((resp: any) => {
            this.persons = resp.data;
            callback({
              recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
              recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
              data: [],
            });
          });
      },
      columns: [{ data: 'id' }, { data: 'firstName' }, { data: 'lastName' }],
    };
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-tests-8e4dxx)

Comment: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way this link may be helpful to you

Comment: use post instead of get. The second parameter of get is for options, not body.